# Trying to adjust the speed of a bat (paddle, in pong) during runtime

Tags: c#, xna

**EDIT 2:** [Pastebin link to the full ball, bat, and AIbat classes.](http://pastebin.com/tpcRX1Ed)

**EDIT:** I've updated the turbo code, and just commented it a bit better. I also have a link to all of my [GameplayScreen code in Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ffi48kY5), as I didn't want to flood this page with it.

I'm making a pong type game. I'm creating a powerup which causes three things to occur:

1) Ball slows down (**working**)
2) screen turns black and white (**working**)
3 Bats slow down (**not working**)

I simply adjust the speed of the ball using the "speed" variable, and all works fine. I'm trying to do the same with the bats, but it is showing no change in the speed during the game. When I debug however, after the powerup is activated, I can hover over the speed variable and see that it has changed from it's default speed of *7.0f* to *30.0f*, but no visible change occurs within the game itself.

I'm also running a debug on screen which displays the speeds of the bats and ball, and I've noticed that the ball's speed changes accordingly, and he right bat (AiBat) does as well. It moves to 30.

For some reason though, the left bat (the player controlled one) remains the same speed. Odd.

I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Why can I change speed in one location and it works fine, but not in another?

```
Class bat
{

        /// <summary>
    /// Controls the bat moving up the screen
    /// </summary>
    public void MoveUp()
    {
        SetPosition(Position + new Vector2(0, -moveSpeed * elapsedTime));

    }

        /// <summary>
    /// Updates the position of the AI bat, in order to track the ball
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void UpdatePosition(Ball ball, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        size.X = (int)Position.X;
        size.Y = (int)Position.Y;

        elapsedTime = 50.0f * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        // Just here for debugging. Hitting Z WORKS FINE and slows the bats down
        previous = current;
        current = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (current.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
        {
            elapsedTime = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 5.0f;
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
Class GameplayScreen
{

  .......
  private int disableCooldown;
  private int coolDown;
  private int powerDisableCooldown = 2000;
  private int powerEnableCooldown = 5000;
  ......


        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, bool otherScreenHasFocus, bool coveredByOtherScreen)

                // Updating bat position
                leftBat.UpdatePosition(ball, gameTime);
                rightBat.UpdatePosition(ball, gameTime);

                if (gScaleActivated == true)
                {
                    leftBat.moveSpeed = 30.0f;
                    rightBat.moveSpeed = 30.0f;
                }


                // If spaceBar is down and the turbo bar is not empty, activate turbo. If not, turbo remains off 
                if (input.ActivateTurbo(ControllingPlayer))
                {
                    if (disableCooldown > 0)
                    {
                        leftBat.isTurbo = true;
                        coolDown = powerEnableCooldown;
                        leftBat.moveSpeed = 30.0f;
                        disableCooldown -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        leftBat.DisableTurbo();
                    }
                }

                    // If spacebar is not down, begin to refill the turbo bar
                else
                {
                    leftBat.DisableTurbo();
                    coolDown -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                    // If the coolDown timer is not in effect, then the bat can use Turbo again
                    if (coolDown < 0)
                    {
                        disableCooldown = powerDisableCooldown;
                    }
                }

                // Makes sure that if Turbo is on, it is killd it after () seconds
                if (leftBat.isTurbo)
                {
                    disableCooldown -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logic to trigger Powerups
    /// </summary>
    private void PowerupActivated(object sender, PowerupEventArgs e)
    {
       ...........
                           case PowerupType.SlowMo:
                    {
                        this.SlowMo(gScaleActivated);
                        gScaleActivated = true;
                        break;
                    }
       ...........
    }


    // Activates the SlowMo and grayscale effect for the powerup.
    public void SlowMo(bool gScaleActivated)
    {
                    gScaleActivated = true;
                    ball.SlowMoBall();
                    AudioManager.Instance.PlaySoundEffect("SlowMotion1");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening in the disableTurbo() method? And where are you setting a breakpoint to check for the speed variable value?

Comment: Turbo is disabled after a set period of time, I believe I have it at 5 seconds at the moment. It deducts it from elapsedTime as the game is running.

I'm also running a debug on screen which displays the speeds of the bats and ball, and I've noticed that the ball's speed changes accordingly, and he right bat (AiBat) does as well. It moves to 30.

For some reason though, the left bat (the player controlled one) remains the same speed. Odd.

Comment: Where are you setting the bat speeds back to their normal speeds?

Comment: I have another method in my bat class called ReturnToNormalSpeed(), where the ball returns to 7.0f. When the powerup expires, it calls that, in addition to a method with the same name in the ball class, which also returns it to the default speed.

Comment: Do you see the speed change back to the normal speed in your onscreen display? Or does it stay at 30?

Comment: Yes, when the powerups are deactivated I have it doing the setting the ball back to its normal speed, and the same with the bats. It also returns the screen to having color.

I must have messed something up recently however, because one of the powerups (Growball) is no longer activating and now the SlowMo powerup is not deactivated. Ugggh.

Comment: what is the difference between `coolDown` and `disableCooldown`. Also, would you mind pasting the entire code into pastebin?

Comment: Geroge, I figured out why my ball wasn't changing size. I changed the spritebatc.Draw so that the ball rotates, and didn't change it in my powerup. It not works.

Niko: I've updated the turbo code, and just commented it a bit better. I also have a link to all of my [GameplayScreen code in Pastebin][1], as I didn't want to flood this page with it. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I've now realized that my ball does not return to normal size after the powerup expires either. Odd.

Comment: Could you post the complete Bat and AIBat classes on pastebin?

Comment: Sure thing. I didn't see this earlier, otherwise I would have done it sooner. Thank you again for taking the time to assist me! I've posted the link in the update above.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of the classes, one guess is that because you do the UpdatePositions call before setting moveSpeed in Update, the left bat gets its moveSpeed reset further down so it remains briefly at its reset value when you do the UpdatePosition call each cycle. To test this, try setting moveSpeed before you update the positions?

```
            leftBat.UpdatePosition(ball, gameTime);
            rightBat.UpdatePosition(ball, gameTime);

            if (gScaleActivated == true)
            {
                leftBat.moveSpeed = 30.0f;
                rightBat.moveSpeed = 30.0f;
            }
```

Comment: Where do you see that one is updated before the other? I'm a bit lost there.

Comment: In the class GameplayScreen's Update method, I've added the lines I'm thinking of to my answer. Try calling the UpdatePosition last instead. Still just a guess though ;)

Comment: Still no good :/. I've since removed that if (gScaleActivated......) line as I realized that it had no effect on the code. I'm still not sure why only one bat updates though, and not the other. Very peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's weird. I solved it. I simply commented out my turbo code. I'm not sure why it had anything to do with the slowMo, as this is only activated when I hit spacebar.

```
                    #region Turbo stuff
                // If spaceBar is down and the turbo bar is not empty, activate turbo. If not, turbo remains off 
                if (input.ActivateTurbo(ControllingPlayer))
                {
                    if (disableCooldown > 0)
                    {
                        leftBat.isTurbo = true;
                        coolDown = powerEnableCooldown;
                        leftBat.moveSpeed = 30.0f;
                        disableCooldown -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        leftBat.DisableTurbo();
                    }
                }

                    // If spacebar is not down, begin to refill the turbo bar
                else
                {
                    leftBat.DisableTurbo();
                    coolDown -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                    // If the coolDown timer is not in effect, then the bat can use Turbo again
                    if (coolDown < 0)
                    {
                        disableCooldown = powerDisableCooldown;
                    }
                }

                // Makes sure that if Turbo is on, it is killd it after () seconds
                if (leftBat.isTurbo)
                {
                    disableCooldown -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                }

                if (disableCooldown < 0)
                {
                    leftBat.isTurbo = false;
                }

                #endregion
```